# SharePoint 2010 Enterprise To SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to move from SharePoint 2010 Enterprise to SharePoint Foundation 2013? If so, are there any obstacles that I should be aware of?

Comment: The additional features that are introduced in the SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition, might not be available at SharePoint 2013 foundation. The functionality implemented based on that features might break.

Comment: Is there a good way to compare features and to see whats currently being used vs what may be missing?

Comment: You may go in the "site collection features" & "manage site features" of both the sites and check whatsoever features are activated or kept deactivated.

Comment: Its also not about only the features that make a difference there are many service applications too, that make a difference. Enterprise editions have lots of service applications available as compared to Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this upgrade as mentioned by you is not recommended, since the points that we discussed above in our comments. There are supported starting and ending editions given in the below provided links. For more information you can go through the below mentioned links,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx

[Best way to migrate a site collection from Enterprise to Foundation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23272/best-way-to-migrate-a-site-collection-from-enterprise-to-foundation)

http://sharepointengineer.com/2012/11/15/sharepoint-2010-to-2013-upgrade-step-by-step-2/